# Controlling custom message in IF Else

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, if-statement

I have developed text boxes to add date range to pick specific records within that date range.
I have written IF ELSE for that if Both text boxes are empty then SHOW ERROR MESSAGE but problem is that when i first time call page then it shows same error. I know why because in first attempt text boxes are empty but how to control this ?

```
public ActionResult ShowMyAtdByDate(String DateFrom, String DateTo) 
    {
        int empId = 0;
        int.TryParse((string)Session["Employee"], out empId); // parse variable to int and saves the result in empId
     //   IEnumerable<GetMyAtd_DateResult> MyAtdRecord = DataContext.GetMyAtd_Date(DateFrom,DateTo,empId).ToList();

        if (DateFrom != "" && DateTo == "" && empId > 0)
        {
            IEnumerable<GetMyAtd_DateResult> MyAtdRecord = DataContext.GetMyAtd_Date(DateFrom,null, empId).ToList();
            ViewBag.Dates = "Records for" + " " + DateFrom;
            return View(MyAtdRecord);

        }
        else if (DateFrom == "" && DateTo != "" && empId > 0)
        {
            IEnumerable<GetMyAtd_DateResult> MyAtdRecord = DataContext.GetMyAtd_Date( null, DateTo, empId).ToList();
            ViewBag.Dates = "Records for" + " " + DateTo;
            return View(MyAtdRecord);
        }
        else if (DateFrom != "" && DateTo != "" && empId > 0)
        {
            IEnumerable<GetMyAtd_DateResult> MyAtdRecord = DataContext.GetMyAtd_Date(DateFrom, DateTo, empId).ToList();
            ViewBag.Dates = "Records from" + " " + DateFrom + " " + "to" + " " + DateTo;
            return View(MyAtdRecord);
        }
        else if (DateFrom == "" && DateTo == "" && empId > 0)
        {
            IEnumerable<GetMyAtd_DateResult> MyAtdRecord = DataContext.GetMyAtd_Date(null, null, empId).ToList();
            ViewBag.Dates = "No dates selection";
            return View(MyAtdRecord);
        }
        else if(empId <=0 )
        {
            return RedirectToAction("IsAuth_Page","Home");
        }

        return View();


    }
```

View:

```
@{

     var grid = new WebGrid(ViewData.Model, rowsPerPage: 25);

 }

 @if (Model.Count > 0)
 {
     <div id="AllMyAtd_ByDate">
       @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
                                        grid.Column("EmplID", "Employee ID"),
                                        grid.Column("EmplName", "Employee Name"),
                                        grid.Column("ShiftID", "Shift ID"),
                                        grid.Column("DateVisited", "Date of Visit"),
                                        grid.Column("InTime", "In Time"),
                                        grid.Column("TimeOut", "Time Out"),
                                        grid.Column("OverTime", "Over Time"),
                                        grid.Column("TotalWorkingTime", "Total Working Time")
                                      ))
     </div>
 }
 else
 {
     <h4 class="error">Sorry Record Doesn't Exist for selected date(s)</h4>  
 }
```

When i first browse to this page then this appears which actually should appear only if i leave both text boxes empty.

Answer (score 1):

The first time an user enters this page, it will be as a GET-request. You could remove this logic out of the GET-method (because it doesn't need to be executed when it is the first time) and put it in the POST-method, since this is the HTTP-method that will be used when the user has submitted the form.

---

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ShowMyAtdByDate()
{
    int empId = 0;
    int.TryParse((string)Session["Employee"], out empId);

    if (empId <= 0)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("IsAuth_Page", "Home");
    }

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowMyAtdByDate(string dateFrom, string dateTo)
{
    if (dateFrom != "" && dateTo == "" && empId > 0)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (dateFrom == "" && dateTo != "" && empId > 0)
    {
        ...
    }
    etc...
}
```

And make sure in your view your form has the method POST

Comment: I meant that you need to have two methods in your controller: one for GET (which is almost empty (maybe only the if(empId <=0 ) { return RedirectToAction("IsAuth_Page","Home"); })). And the second method will handle the POST, which will include your logic.

Comment: i don't really understand your answer sir, please can you edit my code  ?